# CSP for iFrame without any src attribute

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, content-security-policy

I am looking for recommendations on how to implement our CSP policy. We have an Angular SPA application, that has an iframe without any src attribute. We populate the content of the iframe dynamically based on markup that we receive from an API. The markup that is returned from the API could have scripts that are not controlled by us. The SPA application will render the markup, including executing the scripts that get returned from the API as part of the markup.
The issue here is that a potentially malicious script could get returned from the API, which could hijack user information from the parent SPA application.

In this situation, how do we go about implementing CSP policy for the SPA application? I understand that there might not be a way to restrict hijack without doing some major architecture changes in the way that the content is rendered by the SPA. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You might have better luck asking this over at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ or https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. Posting this on security security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If the remote source returns specific scripts, you might be able to set a hash policy that allows that specific script. If they're returning a script that changes, you have to either a) block it, or b) trust them.

Example hash:

`Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'sha256-B2yPHKaXnvFWtRChIbabYmUBFZdVfKKXHbWtWidDVF8='`

Putting it another way: If it's a known script, you can allow that exact, known script. If it's an unknown script, how can you possible write a policy for the unknown?

There is also `strict-dynamic`, which basically says "allow unknown scripts that are loaded by this known script (e.g. Google APIs)", but indeed in that case you are trusting that other source to not serve you malicious code.  What this does do is prevent *other* random unknown stuff from loading from other sources; it's a partial restriction.

Comment: Yes.. And therein lies the problem. We have no control over the scripts or what they in turn use.

Comment: Oh, and Possibility 3: find a different provider who does it better